# Execute the C# console exe with command line arguments from VB Project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How to call an **exe** written in C# which accepts command line arguments from VB.NET application.

For Example, Let's assume the C# exe name is "**SendEmail.exe**" and its 4 arguments are *From ,TO ,Subject and Message* and If I have placed the exe in the C drive. This is how I call from the command prompt

```
C:\SendEmail from@email.com,to@email.com,test subject, "Email Message " & vbTab & vbTab & "After two tabs" & vbCrLf & "I am next line"
```

I would like to call this "SendEmail" exe from the VB.NET application and pass the command line arguments from VB (arguments will be using vb Syntax like vbCrLf, VBTab etc). This problem may look silly but I am trying to divide the complex problem into series of smaller issues and conquer it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is the a console application or do you want to run a process from the command line?

Comment: I found the solution in this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your question has the C# tag, I'll suggest a C# solution you can re-spin in your preferred language.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This will run the EXE for the user. If arguments are passed, then arguments will be used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="incomingShortcutItem"></param>
    /// <param name="xtraArguments"></param>
    public static void RunEXE(string incomingExePath, List<string> xtraArguments = null)
    {
        if (File.Exists(incomingExePath))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            if (xtraArguments != null)
            {
                info.Arguments = " " + string.Join(" ", xtraArguments);
            }
            info.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(incomingExePath);
            info.FileName = incomingExePath;
            proc.StartInfo = info;
            proc.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            //do your else thing here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You *might not need* to call it via the console. If it's done in C# and marked public instead of internal or private, or if it relies on a public type, you may be able to add it as a reference in your VB.Net solution and call the method you want directly.

This is so much cleaner and better because you don't have to worry about things like escaping spaces or quotes in your subject or body arguments.

If you have control over the SendMail program, you make it accessible with a few simple changes. By default, a C# Console project gives you something like this:

```
using ....
// several using blocks at the top

// class name
class Program
{
    //static Main() method
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

You can make it available to use from VB.Net like this:

```
using ....
// several using blocks at the top

//Make sure an explicit namespace is declared
namespace Foo
{
    // make the class public
    public class Program
    {
        //make the method public
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. Again, just add the reference in your project, `Import` it at the top of your VB.Net file, and you can call the Main() method directly, without going through the console. It doesn't matter that's it an .exe instead of a .dll. In the .Net world, they're all just assemblies you can use.